# How do I show this formula involving several variables?

Tags: analysis

This is from Woll's "Functions of Several Variables," but there's no proof.

If $g$ is of class $C^k$ ($k \ge 2$) on a convex open set $U$ about $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$, then for each $q \in U$,

$
g(q) = g(p) + \sum_{i=1}^d \frac{\partial g}{\partial r_i} \bigg|_p (r_i(q) - r_i(p)) + \sum_{i,j} (r_i(q) - r_i(p)) (r_j(q) - r_j(p)) \int_0^1 (1-t) \frac{\partial^2g}{\partial r_i \partial r_j} \bigg|_{p + t(q - p)} dt.
$

It looks like Taylor's or mean value theorem. I especially don't understand the integral part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider function 
$$
h(t)=g(p+t(q-p))
$$
and its Taylor series with the remainder in the integral form
$$
h(1)=h(0)+h'(0)+\int\limits_{0}^{1}(1-t)h''(t)dt
$$
Now note that
$$
h(0)=g(p)
$$
$$
h'(0)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^d\frac{\partial g}{\partial r_i}\biggl|_p(r_i(p)-r_i(q))
$$
$$
h''(t)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^d\sum\limits_{j=1}^d\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial r_i\partial r_j}\biggl|_{p+t(q-p)}(r_i(p)-r_i(q))(r_j(p)-r_j(q))
$$